# Web Config rewrite rule

Tags: regex, web-config

I'm trying to write a rule that will pick up any URL where the second slug does not match 'results' and then rewrite the URl

Here's what I have so far.

```
<rule name="accommidationRewrite2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="/accommodation/(!results)/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/accommodation/results/params/location/{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\/accommodation\/(?!results).*?\/(.*)
```

Try this.The problem with your regex was that lookaheads dont consume a string.So your regex was effectively matching two `/` .See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qC9cH4/20

Comment: Thanks, That helps a lot. Here is what I ended up with     <rule name="accommidationRewrite2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="accommodation/(?!results).*?(.*)/" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm/?path=/accommodation/results/params/location/{R:1}/" />
</rule>